# Jquery File Upload - Imágenes permitidas

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

me gustaría que el plugin de Jquery File Upload admitiera el tipo de fichero psd. Mediante imagemagick lo convertiría en una miniatura con extensión .jpg. El principal problema es que no encuentro donde puedo indicar los ficheros permitidos.

Parece una tarea fácil pero no lo es del todo.

Pienso que una opción lógica sería pasarle como opción los ficheros permitidos desde la página desde donde llamamos a la instacia, así:

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
              options: {
                  acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(png|jpe?g|psd|tif?f|tif)$/i,
                  maxFileSize: 524288000, // 500MB = 524288000Bytes
                  limitConcurrentUploads: 3
              }
)};
```

No funciona :(

He encontrado otro script que se llama init.fileupload.js donde también inicializa el control:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'assets/jquery-file-upload/server/php/initUpload.php',
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(png|jpe?g|psd|tif?f|tif)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 524288000, // 500MB = 524288000Bytes
        limitConcurrentUploads: 3
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

});
```

Estoy confuso porque añado la extensión pero no me la acepta el control:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensaba que mediante estos ficheros sería sencillo pero no lo es. He buscado por internet y por StackOverflow pero tampoco he encontrado nada en claro.

Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: podrias revisar esto: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#content-type-negotiation

Comment: @Tegito123 gracias por tu comentario pero ya revisé la documentación antes de abrir el post. No supe encontrar la forma de configurar la aceptación de las imágenes psd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [la documentación](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-restrict-the-file-selection-dialog-to-show-only-specific-file-types) encontre lo siguiente:

> Puede utilizar el atributo accept en el campo de tipo archivo para limitar
>   la selección del tipo de archivo, aunque esto parece ser compatible solo
>   con Google Chrome y Opera. Un ejemplo de limitación de archivos a imágenes PNG:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/png" multiple>
```

Podrias intentar con esto:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.tif,.tiff,image/psd" multiple>
```

Si esto no te funciona igual podrias intentar usar el metodo `add` que incluye el plugin y dependiendo la extensión del archivo procedor o no. Te dejo un ejemplo que encontre en Stackoverflow en ingles:

```
add: function (e, data) {
    var goUpload = true; // Bandera que nos servirá para saber si enviar o no la data
    var uploadFile = data.files[0]; // Optenemos el primer archivo (si permites multiples archivos quizas quieras hacer un foreach)
    if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) { // testeamos si contienen la extención que nos interesa
        common.notifyError('You must select an image file only'); // Mensaje de error
        goUpload = false; // Ponemos la bandera en false
    }
    if (uploadFile.size > 2000000) { // Limite de los archivos a 2mb
        common.notifyError('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
        goUpload = false; // Ponemos la bandera en false
    }
    if (goUpload) { // Si la bandera es igual a true entonces enviamos la data, de otra forma no se envia nada
        data.submit();
    }
},
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14435204/8067370

Saludos!

Comment: me funcionó el parámetro 'accept' del campo input. Gracias por tu respuesta.